# Passing a friend GET ID to another page

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have asked this question before but I couldn't understand the answer maybe because it didn't work for me.

I have a developed a chat application. Once a user submits using keyup, it works well i.e inserted into database and also selected just fine and the message is even displayed. The page being refreshed by javascript is load.php which has php code doing the selection like this;

`SELECT * FROM chat WHERE sender_id=$_SESSION['id']`

This is working just fine. But when I change it to

`SELECT * FROM chat WHERE sender_id=$_SESSION['id'] AND receipent_id=$_GET['id']`

it is not working simply because the `$_GET['id']` of a selected member in the home page is not being passed to the load.php which is being refreshed by javascript every .....milliseconds so that online messages of the session id and the selected member should show in the message display.
I refresh the `load.php` using this code on the home page;

```
function refresh(){ 
    setTimeout (function(){ 
        $('#message').load('load.php'); 
        refresh(); 
    }, 2000);
}
```

working just fine.

Now this load.php must select for me messages only for the member selected in the home page. So how can I have this members' id passed on to this load.php on selecting from database?

Will be so grateful for your help programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass $_GET['id'] value try to add in your function this value

```
function refresh(){ setTimeout (function(){ 
    $('#message').load('load.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>');
    refresh(); }, 2000);
}
```

Then load.php will have get value

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has been one of the best answers. I really appreciate. It has worked for me perfectly as I wanted .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add get variable in your code:

```
function refresh(id){ //receive id
    setTimeout (function(){ 
    $('#message').load('load.php?id='+id); //add id variable to the url 
    refresh(); 
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: either that or retrieve the id variable from somewhere else (i.e. dom element, hidden input, localStorage etc)

Comment: Yes, depends on your situation and requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to pass the `GET` value on the query string.  Currently you're requesting this:

```
load('load.php')
```

If you want an `id` value, add one:

```
load('load.php?id=' + someValue)
```

If you need to *get* that value from the *current* query string in JavaScript, there are [a number of ways to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript).  Though, when you initially load the page, if the value is available then it would be trivial to output it to the page from PHP code in the first place.  Something like this:

```
var someValue = <?php echo $someValue; ?>;
```

Keep in mind a few things here:

- If the value is a string then you need to specify quotes in the JavaScript, not in the PHP.
- Don't blindly echo user-submitted values to the page, that's a security vulnerability.
- Users ***can*** change this value in your `load.()` call.  So your approach may make it trivial for users to "impersonate" other users in your application.  Make sure you *always* validate authorization server-side.
- Your example SQL queries look like glaring [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  You're probably going to want to read up on validating user input and [using prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped me put it all together.